# Rigid Body objects pass through Basket

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I am just a beginner of blender. I use the function of rigid body but objects keep passing through the basket. I searched and tried different methods from the internet but still not successful. For your information, the basket has three pasts which are parent together.

Here is my file link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1baVak34Urbc6wQd-Der2rSoRO2KTZZU-/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In 2.9 there will be the *Compound Parent* shape, explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5zBqQELdVU) by CGMatter, that may make things even more accurate, for the moment here is a solution with *Convex Hull* that works:

- First, don't keep your vertical cylinder.
- Also, join the trim of the basket to the basket, for the moment it is another object without any physics. If you join it to the basket it will be taken into account
- In the *Properties panel > Scene > Rigid Body World*, increase a bit the *Steps Per Second* value up to 100, I don't know how it works exactly but it looks like it helps to simulate physics more accurately.
- Select one of your lemon, in the *Properties panel > Physics > Collisions > Shape*, choose *Convex Hull* instead of *Mesh*.

[image]

- Keep this lemon selected, select all the other lemons, for example with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (Select Linked) > *Material*, and in the header menu > *Object > Rigid Body*, click on *Copy From Active* (by the way if all your lemons are the same you could have linked-duplicated them with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, but you can simply make a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Object Data* and all the objects share the same mesh).
- Play the animation, it should work fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The problem is solved following your steps.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Z3nD9S1 < Rigid Body World

Comment: @mevsme Hello, what do you mean, have I missed something? (it's a long time ago)

Comment: @moonboots hello, it's all fine, I just couldn't find rigid body world settings by text description, and I was frustrated that there are no any images. Now I added one.